# Handling Overlap with TriggerSphere and other Actor?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, unreal-engine4

I have an ATriggerSphere which is set to follow the character and is meant to respond to overlaps with other actors. I'm attempting to do this like so:

```
void AScrollsCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    // Call the base class  
    Super::BeginPlay();

    //Create activate trigger radius
    activateRadiusTrigger = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<ATriggerSphere>(ATriggerSphere::StaticClass(),GetActorLocation(), GetActorRotation());
    activateRadiusTrigger->SetActorHiddenInGame(false);
    USphereComponent* colSphere = (USphereComponent*) activateRadiusTrigger->GetCollisionComponent();
    colSphere->SetSphereRadius(ACTIVATE_RADIUS);
    colSphere->bGenerateOverlapEvents = true;
    colSphere->SetCollisionResponseToAllChannels(ECollisionResponse::ECR_Overlap);
    colSphere->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AScrollsCharacter::OnOverlapActivateSphere);

}

void AScrollsCharacter::OnOverlapActivateSphere(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("We got a collision."));
}

void AScrollsCharacter::Tick(float deltaSeconds)
{
    Super::Tick(deltaSeconds);

    //Set the radius trigger to follow the player
    activateRadiusTrigger->SetActorLocation(GetActorLocation());
}
```

OnOverlapActivateSphere doesn't seem to be getting called on collisions, though. Since the character is inside this sphere and I haven't told the trigger to ignore it yet, I would expect the message to print every tick. Am I misunderstanding or missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

No, it's not going to be called every tick. OnOverlapActivateSphere is only going to be called **once** when it **starts** overlapping. So, in order for it to be called again, you have to move your object out of the sphere and then move it inside again. The fact that you are teleporting your trigger every tick to the characters position doesn't mean that your player gets out of it.

**If it's not even called once**

Check out the [collision overview](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Physics/Collision/Overview/index.html) provided by Epic Games (creators of UE4). So:

1. Make sure that you have at least one of your object set to **overlap** the other;
2. Make sure that you have Generate Overlap Events check for your sphere (but I see you've set it to true in the code, so it should be fine);

**Suggestions**

It looks like you don't need a separate actor to be a trigger. It's attached to your character anyway. I would suggest making it a component instead. You can inherit from USphereComponent, implement your trigger logic, make this component a subobject of the character, and attach it to the root component in the constructor (not on BeginPlay).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've taken your advice from steps 1 and 2 and modified my code above slightly to reflect that. Sadly, ensuring that the actors **overlap** each other did not solve my problem; they still don't register overlap events.

Comment: @nathan have you tried console command "Show Collision" during play to make sure that the trigger sphere is where you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes I have. The sphere is drawn on screen and absolutely overlaps the other actors physically.